# Taking screenshot of a device screen using c#

Tags: compact-framework

Hii...
Is there any way to take screenshot of the application running on WIN CE5.0 device screen.
Thanxxx  in advance....

Answer (score 8):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ScreenShot
{
    public class Program
    {
        enum RasterOperation : uint { SRC_COPY = 0x00CC0020 }

        [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
        static extern int BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, RasterOperation rasterOperation);

        [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

        [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
        private static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);

        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            Rectangle bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                IntPtr dstHdc = graphics.GetHdc();
                BitBlt(dstHdc, 0, 0, bounds.Width, bounds.Height, hdc, 0, 0,
                RasterOperation.SRC_COPY);
                graphics.ReleaseHdc(dstHdc);
            }
            bitmap.Save("screenshot.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use OpenNetCF SDF

http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/03/11/ScreenCaptureInTheCompactFramework.aspx

```
// create a bitmap and graphics objects for the capture
Drawing.Bitmap destinationBmp = new Drawing.Bitmap(Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Drawing.Graphics g = Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(destinationBmp);
GraphicsEx gx = GraphicsEx.FromGraphics(g);

// capture the current screen
gx.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

// save the file
destinationBmp.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

// clean house
gx.Dispose();
g.Dispose();
destinationBmp.Dispose();
```